# Does windows server VDI offer any support for zero clients

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, vdi, thin-client

I have an acer network display which is capable of booting to the network and connect to a server capable of rendering virtual desktop. It doesn't have a CPU of its own. I am current using a physical card on the server which serves as the thin client services provider.. I am wondering if I can get rid of the card and use some native service offered by window server? Basically I would want a Zero client, where the client doesn't have an OS.